# Is there a way to restrict a React component's children's types?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, user-interface

I'm creating a UI library for React, but I'm no TypeScript wizard. Yet.

This element uses the Radix UI's  component, which merges the props so we can use composition if necessary:

```
<Heading asChild>
    <p>This is not a heading anymore, but it contains its styles.</p>
</Heading>
```

Is there a way to restrict the types of children the  component can have just using static types? If not, do we have to use runtime type checking? Are PropTypes the best and only way of doing this?

Heading component:

```
import { forwardRef, type HTMLAttributes } from 'react'
import { Slot } from '@radix-ui/react-slot'
import { type VariantProps, cva } from 'class-variance-authority'
import { cn } from '~/utils/misc.ts'

/**
 * Semantics: figure out if there's a way to restrict the children types to only be text
 *
 * Design: figure out which design variants to use (size, weight, alignment)
 *
 * Functionality: whatever a text node can have
 *
 *  */

const headingVariants = cva('', {
    variants: {
        weight: {
            thin: 'font-thin',
            extralight: 'font-extralight',
            light: 'font-light',
            normal: 'font-normal',
            medium: 'font-medium',
            semibold: 'font-semibold',
            bold: 'font-bold',
            extrabold: 'font-extrabold',
            black: 'font-black',
        },
        align: {
            left: 'text-left',
            center: 'text-center',
            right: 'text-right',
        },
    },
    defaultVariants: {
        weight: 'bold',
        align: 'left',
    },
})

type asType = 'h1' | 'h2' | 'h3' | 'h4' | 'h5' | 'h6'

type HeadingProps = HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> &
    VariantProps<typeof headingVariants> & {
        asChild?: boolean
        as?: asType
    }

const Heading = forwardRef<HTMLHeadingElement, HeadingProps>(({ children, className, asChild = false, as = 'h1', weight = 'bold', align = 'left', ...props }, ref) => {
    const Comp = asChild ? Slot : as
    return (
        <Comp ref={ref} className={cn(headingVariants({ weight, align }), className)} {...props}>
            {children}
        </Comp>
    )
})
Heading.displayName = 'Heading'

export { Heading }
```

I tried searching Google/MSDN/ChatGPT for some kind of HTMLInlineOrTextElement interface, but no such interface exists.